# What is the proper way to declare a delegate variable?

Tags: cocoa, delegates, xcode6, protocols

In MyModel.h, I declared a delegate variable like this:

```
@property(weak) IBOutlet id <MyProtocol> delegate;
```

I've also seen a delegate variable declared like this:

```
@property(weak) IBOutlet NSObject <MyProtocol>* delegate;
```

I'm wondering which I should use.

Also, Xcode 6.2 indicates I'm doing something wrong because when I connect the delegate outlet in IB, Xcode still shows an empty circle to the left of the declaration instead of a filled in circle.  This is what I did:

1) In IB, I dragged on Object out of the Library onto the dock, and I changed its class to: MyModel.

2) In IB, I dragged another Object onto the dock, and I changed its class to: MyController.  I declared the MyController class like this:

```
@interface MyController : NSObject <MyProtocol>

@property(strong) IBOutlet MyModel* model;

@end
```

3) In IB, I hooked up the delegate outlet for the MyModel Object to the MyController Object.

But in Xcode, it still shows an empty circle to the left of the line:

```
@property(weak) IBOutlet id <MyProtocol> delegate;
```

In other words, Xcode is saying the outlet is not connected to anything--yet my app is able to communicate with the controller using the delegate property.

If I delete `<MyProtocol>` from that line, the circle to the left of the line fills in, i.e. Xcode is saying the outlet is now connected to something.  Is that an Xcode bug?

Here are the files for my HelloDelegate app:

MyProtocol.h:

```
//
//  MyProtocol.h
//  HelloDelegate
//


@class MyModel;  //#import "MyModel.h" doesn't work for some reason

@protocol MyProtocol

-(void)sayHello:(MyModel*)model;

@end
```

MyModel.h:

```
//
//  MyModel.h
//  HelloDelegate
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MyController.h"

@interface MyModel : NSObject

@property NSString* name;

-(id)initWithName:(NSString*)name;
-(void)doStuff;

@end
```

MyModel.m:

```
//
//  MyModel.m
//  HelloDelegate
//

#import "MyModel.h"

@interface MyModel()

@property(weak) IBOutlet id <MyProtocol> delegate;


@end


@implementation MyModel

-(void)doStuff {
    [[self delegate] sayHello:self];
}

-(id) init {
    return [self initWithName:@"world"];
}

//Designated initializer:
-(id) initWithName:(NSString *)name {

    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self setName:name];
    }

    return self;
}


@end
```

MyController.h:

```
//
//  MyController.h
//  HelloDelegate
//


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MyProtocol.h"

@interface MyController : NSObject <MyProtocol>

@property(strong) IBOutlet MyModel* model;

@end
```

MyController.m:

```
//
//  MyController.m
//  HelloDelegate
//


#import "MyController.h"
#import "MyModel.h"
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface MyController()

@property(weak) IBOutlet NSTextField* label;

@end

@implementation MyController

-(void)sayHello:(MyModel*)model {

    NSString* labelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello, %@!", [model name]];
    [[self label] setStringValue:labelText];
}


@end
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  HelloDelegate
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MyController.h"
#import "MyModel.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (strong) IBOutlet MyController* controller;

@end


@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    [[[self controller] model] doStuff];

}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

@end
```

Comment: "I'm wondering which I should use" Well, "should" is kind of subjective. It would be better to ask what the difference is; there are some important differences as far as the compiler is concerned.

Comment: @matt, Thanks for the response.  I had some inkling of that.  Does the id declaration copy the object into the variable, whereas the pointer declaration creates a (weak) reference?  I was also wondering about that darn blank connection circle next to the variable declaration.  Why doesn't Xcode fill it in after I make the connection in IB?  I feel like Xcode is telling me the declaration is faulty.

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with memory management, and the Xcode circle thing is just a quirk (Interface Builder has never been very good at dealing with protocols).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference comes along when you type something as `id <SomeProtocol>` and then try to send it a message such as `respondsToSelector:` and the compiler won't let you. It comes as a surprise - or at least it sure [came as a surprise to me](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2013/Oct/msg00121.html) - that `id <SomeProtocol>` is *not a form of `id`*. The *only* messages you can send to such a beast without casting are those defined in the protocol. That's in stark contrast to `id` plain and simple, which can be sent *any* known message.

Thus, in my view, as in that of [those who know better than I](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2013/Oct/msg00143.html), `NSObject <SomeProtocol>*` is better, because now this thing is seen by the compiler as an NSObject, and can be sent all the messages declared for NSObject.

Comment: Alternatively, `SomeProtocol` can inherit from the `NSObject` protocol, as most of the Apple protocols do.

Comment: Sorry that was covered in your first link, but I think it's worth having a mention of it here.

Comment: @jrturton Agreed, glad you mentioned that explicitly.

Comment: @jrturton, Thanks for the insights *people*.

Comment: *then try to send it a message such as respondsToSelector: and the compiler won't let you.*  I was working through an example that used the `respondsToSelector:` check before calling a protocol method, and I thought, *That doesn't make sense, I should be able to call a protocol method without checking*, so I did some research, and then I eliminated the `respondsToSelector:` check.  I imagine I would have been very frustrated if I hadn't!  (I understand that if the protocol method is optional, then you have to do that check.)

Comment: @jrturton, *SomeProtocol can inherit from the NSObject protocol*--Also, Xcode 6.2 autocompletes that inheritance for you when you type `@protocol`.  I erased `<NSObject>` because I didn't know what it was for.